# Sorting input radio boxes alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort this items alphabetically but it is not sorting all items as it should be. Can you give me some ideas why it is not working ?
Here is my fiddle example.

[`jsFiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/kn42tj3e/)

```js
handleAlphaOrder = function() {
    var fieldItem = $('.field_item');
    var sorted = $(fieldItem.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).find('label').text() > $(b).find('label').text()
    }));

    fieldItem.each(function(i) {
        $(this).after(sorted.eq(i));
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" id="productspage-category-women">
    <label for="productspage-category-women">Women</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-2" id="productspage-category-womenbags">
    <label for="productspage-category-womenbags">Women's bags</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-4" id="productspage-category-jewellery">
    <label for="productspage-category-jewellery">Jewellery</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" id="productspage-category-men">
    <label for="productspage-category-men">Men</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-2" id="productspage-category-menbags">
    <label for="productspage-category-menbags">Men's bags</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-4" id="productspage-category-menshoes">
    <label for="productspage-category-menshoes">Men's shoes</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-1" id="productspage-category-baby">
    <label for="productspage-category-baby">Baby</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-3" id="productspage-category-girl">
    <label for="productspage-category-girl">Girl</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4" id="productspage-category-home">
    <label for="productspage-category-home">Home</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-2" id="productspage-category-bed">
    <label for="productspage-category-bed">Bed</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-5" id="productspage-category-kitchen">
    <label for="productspage-category-kitchen">Kitchen</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-7" id="productspage-category-lighting">
    <label for="productspage-category-lighting">Lighting</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-10" id="productspage-category-outdoor">
    <label for="productspage-category-outdoor">Outdoor</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-1" id="productspage-category-haircare">
    <label for="productspage-category-haircare">Hair care</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-3" id="productspage-category-mengrooming">
    <label for="productspage-category-mengrooming">Men's grooming</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-6" id="productspage-category-skincare">
    <label for="productspage-category-skincare">Skincare</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6" id="productspage-category-lifestyle">
    <label for="productspage-category-lifestyle">Lifestyle</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-4" id="productspage-category-foodsupplements">
    <label for="productspage-category-foodsupplements">Food supplements</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-5" id="productspage-category-treatments">
    <label for="productspage-category-treatments">Treatments</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-6" id="productspage-category-electronics">
    <label for="productspage-category-electronics">Electronics</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="" id="productspage-category-all">
    <label for="productspage-category-all">All</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-1" id="productspage-category-womenaccessories">
    <label for="productspage-category-womenaccessories">Women's accessories</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-3" id="productspage-category-womenclothing">
    <label for="productspage-category-womenclothing">Women's clothing</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-5" id="productspage-category-womenshoes">
    <label for="productspage-category-womenshoes">Women's shoes</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-1" id="productspage-category-menaccessories">
    <label for="productspage-category-menaccessories">Men's accessories</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-3" id="productspage-category-menclothing">
    <label for="productspage-category-menclothing">Men's clothing</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3" id="productspage-category-kids">
    <label for="productspage-category-kids">Kids</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-2" id="productspage-category-boy">
    <label for="productspage-category-boy">Boy</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-4" id="productspage-category-toys">
    <label for="productspage-category-toys">Toys</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-1" id="productspage-category-bath">
    <label for="productspage-category-bath">Bath</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-3" id="productspage-category-childrenhome">
    <label for="productspage-category-childrenhome">Children's home</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-6" id="productspage-category-furniture">
    <label for="productspage-category-furniture">Furniture</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-11" id="productspage-category-decor">
    <label for="productspage-category-decor">Decor</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5" id="productspage-category-beauty">
    <label for="productspage-category-beauty">Beauty</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-2" id="productspage-category-makeup">
    <label for="productspage-category-makeup">Makeup</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-5" id="productspage-category-perfume">
    <label for="productspage-category-perfume">Perfume</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-8" id="productspage-category-healthbody">
    <label for="productspage-category-healthbody">Health &amp; body</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-1" id="productspage-category-fooddrinks">
    <label for="productspage-category-fooddrinks">Food &amp; drinks</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-2" id="productspage-category-yoga">
    <label for="productspage-category-yoga">Yoga</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-3" id="productspage-category-gadgets">
    <label for="productspage-category-gadgets">Gadgets</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-7" id="productspage-category-fitness">
    <label for="productspage-category-fitness">Fitness</label>
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle not working

Comment: Do you realize that stackoverflow has the same ability as jsfiddle built in? Use the snipplets button.

Comment: Instead of circumventing the message about including the code as well as the link - please do as it asks.

Comment: sorry guys in the future i am going to include my code like that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your sort is working, but you are not seeing the results because you are incorrectly appending your `field-item`s back to your DOM. Try adding a wrapper around all of your `field-item` divs (`radioGroup` in the example below) and then append to it instead of trying to overlay the existing divs. Overlaying them is what is causing you problems.

Also, you should probably use `localeCompare` when comparing text instead of `>` or `<`. [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Give this a try:

```js
handleAlphaOrder = function() {
  var fieldItem = $('.field_item');
  var sorted = $(fieldItem.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    //return $(a).find('label').text() > $(b).find('label').text()
    return $(a).find('label').text().localeCompare($(b).find('label').text());
  }));

  fieldItem.each(function(i) {
    //$(this).after(sorted.eq(i));
    $('#radioGroup').append(sorted.eq(i));
  });
};

handleAlphaOrder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radioGroup">
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" id="productspage-category-women">
        <label for="productspage-category-women">Women</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-2" id="productspage-category-womenbags">
        <label for="productspage-category-womenbags">Women's bags</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-4" id="productspage-category-jewellery">
        <label for="productspage-category-jewellery">Jewellery</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" id="productspage-category-men">
        <label for="productspage-category-men">Men</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-2" id="productspage-category-menbags">
        <label for="productspage-category-menbags">Men's bags</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-4" id="productspage-category-menshoes">
        <label for="productspage-category-menshoes">Men's shoes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-1" id="productspage-category-baby">
        <label for="productspage-category-baby">Baby</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-3" id="productspage-category-girl">
        <label for="productspage-category-girl">Girl</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4" id="productspage-category-home">
        <label for="productspage-category-home">Home</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-2" id="productspage-category-bed">
        <label for="productspage-category-bed">Bed</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-5" id="productspage-category-kitchen">
        <label for="productspage-category-kitchen">Kitchen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-7" id="productspage-category-lighting">
        <label for="productspage-category-lighting">Lighting</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-10" id="productspage-category-outdoor">
        <label for="productspage-category-outdoor">Outdoor</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-1" id="productspage-category-haircare">
        <label for="productspage-category-haircare">Hair care</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-3" id="productspage-category-mengrooming">
        <label for="productspage-category-mengrooming">Men's grooming</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-6" id="productspage-category-skincare">
        <label for="productspage-category-skincare">Skincare</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6" id="productspage-category-lifestyle">
        <label for="productspage-category-lifestyle">Lifestyle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-4" id="productspage-category-foodsupplements">
        <label for="productspage-category-foodsupplements">Food supplements</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-5" id="productspage-category-treatments">
        <label for="productspage-category-treatments">Treatments</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-6" id="productspage-category-electronics">
        <label for="productspage-category-electronics">Electronics</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="" id="productspage-category-all">
        <label for="productspage-category-all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-1" id="productspage-category-womenaccessories">
        <label for="productspage-category-womenaccessories">Women's accessories</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-3" id="productspage-category-womenclothing">
        <label for="productspage-category-womenclothing">Women's clothing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-5" id="productspage-category-womenshoes">
        <label for="productspage-category-womenshoes">Women's shoes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-1" id="productspage-category-menaccessories">
        <label for="productspage-category-menaccessories">Men's accessories</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-3" id="productspage-category-menclothing">
        <label for="productspage-category-menclothing">Men's clothing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="3" id="productspage-category-kids">
        <label for="productspage-category-kids">Kids</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-2" id="productspage-category-boy">
        <label for="productspage-category-boy">Boy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-4" id="productspage-category-toys">
        <label for="productspage-category-toys">Toys</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-1" id="productspage-category-bath">
        <label for="productspage-category-bath">Bath</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-3" id="productspage-category-childrenhome">
        <label for="productspage-category-childrenhome">Children's home</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-6" id="productspage-category-furniture">
        <label for="productspage-category-furniture">Furniture</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-11" id="productspage-category-decor">
        <label for="productspage-category-decor">Decor</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5" id="productspage-category-beauty">
        <label for="productspage-category-beauty">Beauty</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-2" id="productspage-category-makeup">
        <label for="productspage-category-makeup">Makeup</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-5" id="productspage-category-perfume">
        <label for="productspage-category-perfume">Perfume</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-8" id="productspage-category-healthbody">
        <label for="productspage-category-healthbody">Health &amp; body</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-1" id="productspage-category-fooddrinks">
        <label for="productspage-category-fooddrinks">Food &amp; drinks</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-2" id="productspage-category-yoga">
        <label for="productspage-category-yoga">Yoga</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-3" id="productspage-category-gadgets">
        <label for="productspage-category-gadgets">Gadgets</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field_item">
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-7" id="productspage-category-fitness">
        <label for="productspage-category-fitness">Fitness</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem is that you never call `handleAlphaOrder`, only declare it.

```js
handleAlphaOrder = function() {
  var fieldItem = $('.field_item');
  var sorted = $(fieldItem.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('label').text() > $(b).find('label').text()
  }));

  fieldItem.each(function(i) {
    $(this).after(sorted.eq(i));
  });
};
handleAlphaOrder(); // Call function now
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" id="productspage-category-women">
  <label for="productspage-category-women">Women</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-2" id="productspage-category-womenbags">
  <label for="productspage-category-womenbags">Women's bags</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-4" id="productspage-category-jewellery">
  <label for="productspage-category-jewellery">Jewellery</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" id="productspage-category-men">
  <label for="productspage-category-men">Men</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-2" id="productspage-category-menbags">
  <label for="productspage-category-menbags">Men's bags</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-4" id="productspage-category-menshoes">
  <label for="productspage-category-menshoes">Men's shoes</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-1" id="productspage-category-baby">
  <label for="productspage-category-baby">Baby</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-3" id="productspage-category-girl">
  <label for="productspage-category-girl">Girl</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4" id="productspage-category-home">
  <label for="productspage-category-home">Home</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-2" id="productspage-category-bed">
  <label for="productspage-category-bed">Bed</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-5" id="productspage-category-kitchen">
  <label for="productspage-category-kitchen">Kitchen</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-7" id="productspage-category-lighting">
  <label for="productspage-category-lighting">Lighting</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-10" id="productspage-category-outdoor">
  <label for="productspage-category-outdoor">Outdoor</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-1" id="productspage-category-haircare">
  <label for="productspage-category-haircare">Hair care</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-3" id="productspage-category-mengrooming">
  <label for="productspage-category-mengrooming">Men's grooming</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-6" id="productspage-category-skincare">
  <label for="productspage-category-skincare">Skincare</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6" id="productspage-category-lifestyle">
  <label for="productspage-category-lifestyle">Lifestyle</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-4" id="productspage-category-foodsupplements">
  <label for="productspage-category-foodsupplements">Food supplements</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-5" id="productspage-category-treatments">
  <label for="productspage-category-treatments">Treatments</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-6" id="productspage-category-electronics">
  <label for="productspage-category-electronics">Electronics</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="" id="productspage-category-all">
  <label for="productspage-category-all">All</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-1" id="productspage-category-womenaccessories">
  <label for="productspage-category-womenaccessories">Women's accessories</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-3" id="productspage-category-womenclothing">
  <label for="productspage-category-womenclothing">Women's clothing</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="1-5" id="productspage-category-womenshoes">
  <label for="productspage-category-womenshoes">Women's shoes</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-1" id="productspage-category-menaccessories">
  <label for="productspage-category-menaccessories">Men's accessories</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="2-3" id="productspage-category-menclothing">
  <label for="productspage-category-menclothing">Men's clothing</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="3" id="productspage-category-kids">
  <label for="productspage-category-kids">Kids</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-2" id="productspage-category-boy">
  <label for="productspage-category-boy">Boy</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="3-4" id="productspage-category-toys">
  <label for="productspage-category-toys">Toys</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-1" id="productspage-category-bath">
  <label for="productspage-category-bath">Bath</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-3" id="productspage-category-childrenhome">
  <label for="productspage-category-childrenhome">Children's home</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-6" id="productspage-category-furniture">
  <label for="productspage-category-furniture">Furniture</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="4-11" id="productspage-category-decor">
  <label for="productspage-category-decor">Decor</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5" id="productspage-category-beauty">
  <label for="productspage-category-beauty">Beauty</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-2" id="productspage-category-makeup">
  <label for="productspage-category-makeup">Makeup</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-5" id="productspage-category-perfume">
  <label for="productspage-category-perfume">Perfume</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="5-8" id="productspage-category-healthbody">
  <label for="productspage-category-healthbody">Health &amp; body</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-1" id="productspage-category-fooddrinks">
  <label for="productspage-category-fooddrinks">Food &amp; drinks</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-2" id="productspage-category-yoga">
  <label for="productspage-category-yoga">Yoga</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-3" id="productspage-category-gadgets">
  <label for="productspage-category-gadgets">Gadgets</label>
</div>
<div class="field_item">
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="6-7" id="productspage-category-fitness">
  <label for="productspage-category-fitness">Fitness</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like his sort is incorrect as well, but this is the main issue for sure.

Comment: yea it is not sorting alphabetically .. and i do not have idea why

Comment: Your `sort()` function shouldn't return the result of a `>` or `<` comparison (or any other boolean result). It should return negative, zero, or positive depending on the values of the strings. The result of [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is often used.

Comment: There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but off-the-cuff, something like: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/JXagNZ will work without adding a container.

Comment: @PaulRoub I will not fix other issues than OP asked.